# Almost there with this regex

Tags: regex

I have the following regex that I want to find 'Jersey'. but not 'New Jersey':

```
(?i:\b[^New]\s*Jersey\b)
```

However this is still matching the 'Jersey' in 'New Jersey'. What do I need to change so the regex will recognise that the matched 'Jersey' should be cancelled out by the not to be matched '[^New]'?

Thanks

N.B. this is in SAS, which uses the Perl flavour of regexes.

Answer (score 5):

That is not correct regex since inside character class characters are not grouped. Use `negative lookbehind` like this:

```
(?i)(?<!\bNew)\s+Jersey\b
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nB0sP0/2)